# SSH command not exiting properly

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I wrote a script that SSH to remote servers in loop and run a command, it gets hung after running on last server.Here is my loop script -

```
cat server | while read serName
        do
                cat cmmnds| while read line
                do
                 result=`ssh -f $serName  $line`
                 echo -n ",$result" >> test.csv
        done
echo " " >> test.csv
done
```

Here is how it errors out in the end and have to control+C for exiting out

```
Cannot fork into background without a command to execute.
ssh: illegal option -- d

usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]
Cannot fork into background without a command to execute.
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
Cannot fork into background without a command to execute.
```

Any clue ??

Comment: 1) What is in `servers`? 2) What is in `cmmnds`? Please [edit] your post with more information.

Comment: Add `set -x` before that loop to get a trace of what's going on. Evidently one of your variables doesn't contain what you think it does. [Properly double-quoting variable expansions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) may help. Or it could be as simple as having a blank line.

Comment: I'd go with there being a blank line in each of the two source files.

Comment: And please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try and do this in this manner using `ssh` you might want to use a tool such as `pssh`. This U&L Q&A titled: [Execute a command on multiple hosts, but only print command if it is successful?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123591/7453).

In your case you could take the `server` & command files directly into `pssh` like so:

```
$ pssh -h server -i -I < commands.txt
```

#### Example

Here I've constructed the following 2 files:

```
$ cat servers
skinner
mulder

$ cat commands.txt
date
echo 'hi'
```

Now when I run it:

```
$ pssh -O ForwardX11=no -h servers -i -I < commands.txt
[1] 03:10:03 [SUCCESS] skinner
Fri Jul 17 03:10:03 EDT 2015
hi
[2] 03:10:04 [SUCCESS] mulder
Fri Jul 17 03:06:41 EDT 2015
hi
```

You can either catch the above output like this:

```
$ .... | tee some_log_file.txt
```

Or you can take the `-i` switch out and let `pssh` create separate log files for each server using the `-o <dir>` switch.

```
$ pssh -O ForwardX11=no -h servers -o ~/somedir -I < commands.txt
[1] 03:13:04 [SUCCESS] skinner
[2] 03:13:04 [SUCCESS] mulder
```

Now check the results:

```
$ ls somedir/
mulder  skinner

$ cat somedir/*
Fri Jul 17 03:09:41 EDT 2015
hi
Fri Jul 17 03:13:03 EDT 2015
```

#### References

- https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/
- http://www.theether.org/pssh/docs/0.2.3/pssh-HOWTO.html